# Angular ivy, error with template local variables: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular

I have the message error: "Object is possibly 'null'". in the line `modal.customWidth.extra_large`

My code is:

```
<app-modal
      #modal
      [active]="hasCurrentProduct$ | async"
      [modalWidth]="modal.customWidth.extra_large">
```

Comment: Can you please create a StackBlitz for this because it is too broad. Also, what IDE are you using ?

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm using Angular 9.0.7. Have you managed to find a solution?
I enabled `"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true` and `"strictTemplates": true` in tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `modal` and `customWidth` are not null before accessing their properties.

Change `modal.customWidth.extra_large` to `modal?.customWidth?.extra_large`

Answer (score 0):

There is an [option](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) `strictNullInputTypes` related to this (for input properties).

It's been fixed somewhat with https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32051

But I came up with this for some scenarios:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'default'
})
export class DefaultValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() {}

    transform<T>(value: T | null | undefined, defaultValue: T): T {
        return value ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Then you just add it after the `async`

```
[active]="hasCurrentProduct$ | async | default: false"
```

Makes things super clear and none of this nonsense:

```
[active]="(hasCurrentProduct$ | async) ?? false"
```

Well TBH in this example they're actually about the same - but more complex expressions can benefit.

```
<div [style.width.em]="(catsCount$ | async | default: 1) * 30"></div>


You own {{ (cats$ | async | default: []).length }} cats
```

Comment: The issue that you're mentioning is the same as https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24598 and it seemed to be fixed, but it's not the same as the one in the question.

I'm using Angular 9.0.7 and I still have the same issue.